# How to secure Ant builds?

Tags: security, ant, build, jenkins, continuous-integration

Our company uses ANT to automate build scripts.

Now somebody raised the question how to secure such build scripts agains (accidental or intended) threats?

*Example 1: someone checks in a build script that deletes everything under Windows drive T:\ because that is where the Apache deployment directory is mounted for a particular development machine. Months later, someone else might run the build script and erase everything on T:\ which is a shared drive on this machine.*

*Example 2: an intruder modifies the default build target in a single project to scan the entire local hard disk. The Continuous Integration machine (e.g. Jenkins) is configured to execute the default build target and will therefore send its entire local directory structure to the intruder, even for projects that the intruder should not have access to.*

Any suggestions how to prevent such scenarios (besides "development policies" or "do not mount shared drives")?

My only idea is to use chroot enviroments for builds?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my company, the build scripts (usually a build folder) are an svn:external to another subversion repository that is only controlled by build/release engineers. Developers can control variables such as servers it can deploy to, but not what those functions do. This same code is reused amongst multiple projects in flight, and only a few devops folks can alter it, not the entire development staff.

Addition: When accessing shared resources, we use a system account that has only read access to those resources. Further: jenkins,development projects and build/deploy code are written to handle complete loss of jenkins project workspace and deploy environments. This is basic build automation/deploy automation that leads to infrastructure automation.

Basic rule: Murphy's law is going to happen. You should write scripts that are robust and handle cold start scenarios and not worry about wild intruder theories.

Answer (score 1):

The issues you describe are the same for any code that you execute on the build machine - you could do the same thing using a unit test.

In this case the best solution may be to place your build scripts under source control and have a code review prior to check in.